# lombok in eclipse works in windows 7 when started from the command line, but not when started from the start button

Tags: eclipse, lombok

I have eclipse oxygen on windows 7. I installed lombok.

When I start eclipse from the command line, lombok works:

```
C:\Users\ervelden\eclipse\java-oxygen\eclipse>eclipse.exe
```

But when I start eclipse from the start button, lombok does not work. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at what the starting directory is when you launch it from the start menu. If that doesn't help, you can modify `eclipse.ini`, and provide the full path to `lombok.jar`.

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer.